# Association with alias "x" does not exist on item, sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have an **Item** model that has several userId rows, and i want to include both receiver and sender in my findAll query

```
User.hasMany(Item, {foreignKey: 'received', as: 'received'})
Item.belongsTo(User)

User.hasMany(Item, {as: 'sent', foreignKey: {name:'sent', allowNull: false}})
Item.belongsTo(User)
```

```
let itemsList = await Item.findAndCountAll({
                include: [{association: 'sent'}]
            })
```

However, when i am trying to execute this query with **received** or **sent** **associations**, i get this error:

```
Error: Association with alias "sent" does not exist on item
```

I tried to change associations, but that didn't work.

Comment: Are `Transaction` and `Item` the same model?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to replace the name in this post everywhere, the original name is transaction anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined aliases for associations from `User` to `Item` and that means you can only execute queries where `User` will be the main model and `Item` will be an included model if you indicate these aliases. Just add the other unique aliases in associations from `Item` to `User` and use them in the query:

```js
User.hasMany(Item, {foreignKey: 'received', as: 'received'})
Item.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'received', as: 'receiver' })

User.hasMany(Item, {as: 'sent', foreignKey: {name:'sent', allowNull: false }})
Item.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: {name:'sent', allowNull: false }, as: 'sender' })
```

the query:

```js
let itemsList = await Item.findAndCountAll({
                include: [{association: 'sender'}]
            })
```